# How correctly align text as graphics

Tags: graphics, text

When I try this:

```
Framed@Graphics[{Text[
    Style["Text", FontSize -> 50, Bold, Black, Background -> Green, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"]]}]
```

[image]

I get a centered text with a large empty space around.

How can I align the text e.g. to left or how can I make the frame as large as the text is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
txt = Text[Framed[Style["Text", FontSize -> 150, Bold, Black, 
    FontFamily -> "Calibri"], Background -> Green, ContentPadding -> False]]; 
Graphics[txt, ImageSize -> Rasterize[txt, "RasterSize"]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the second argument of `Text` to specify the position:

```
txtb = Text[Framed[Style["Text", FontSize -> 150, Bold, Black, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"], Background -> Green, ContentPadding -> False], {0, 0}];
Graphics[txtb]
```

> same picture

```
txt2 = Text[Framed[Style["TextTextTextTextText\nTextTextTextTextText", 
     FontSize -> 64, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
     LineSpacing -> {1, -10}], Background -> Green, ContentPadding -> False]];
Graphics[txt2, ImageSize -> Rasterize[txt2, "RasterSize"]]
```

[image]

Using the second approach:

```
txt2b = Text[Framed[Style["TextTextTextTextText\nTextTextTextTextText", 
     FontSize -> 64, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Calibri", 
     LineSpacing -> {1, -10}], Background -> Green, ContentPadding -> False], {0, 0}];
Graphics[txt2b]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 4):

I would use a slightly different approach which gives more flexibility.

```
Graphics[{Green, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], (*Green Background*)
 Inset[Style["Text", FontSize -> 150, Bold, Black,FontFamily -> "Calibri"],
 {0, 0}, {Left, Bottom}]}] (*position and alignment*)
```

[image]

Or some tilting

```
q = Pi/6;
Graphics[{Green, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], 
 Inset[Style["Text", FontSize -> 100, Bold, Black, FontFamily -> "Calibri"],
 {0.5, 0}, {-1,-0.5}, {Cos[q],Sin[q]}]}]
```

[image]

Look at [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) for more options.

---

**For Text in a box**

```
wordbox[text_, fontsize_, fontcolor_, font_, background_] := 
       Framed[ImageCrop@Rasterize@Style[text, FontSize -> fontsize, Bold, fontcolor, 
       FontFamily -> font, Background -> background],
       Background -> background, FrameMargins -> 0]

wordbox["Text", 100, Blue, "Calibri", Red]
wordbox["Texture", 100, Black, "Calibri", Green]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. How to you set the rectangle to the **minimal** size which holds the word "Text"?

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust `ImageSize`

```
Framed[Graphics[{Text[
    Style["Text", FontSize -> 150, Bold, Black, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"]]},  ImageSize -> {275, 105}], 
 Background -> Green]
```

[image]

Or

```
   Framed[Text[
  Style["Text", FontSize -> 150, Bold, Black, 
   FontFamily -> "Calibri"]], Alignment -> Center, 
 Background -> Green, FrameMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False, 
 ImageSize -> {277, 108}]
```

[image]

```
Framed[Text[
  Style["Red Fox jr", FontSize -> 150, Bold, Black, 
   FontFamily -> "Calibri"]], Alignment -> Center, 
 Background -> Green, FrameMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good, but the values `{275, 105}` of `ImageSize` are set manually. Is it possible to find these  values from the given "Text"?

Comment: I don't know how to reduce top and bottom space..